# How to re-enable a filter after disabling with __return_false

Tags: filters

I can disable a filter as follows:

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

This may be a trivial question, but I can't find an answer for it... can I re-enable the filter with the following?

```
add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_true' );
```

If not, how can I re-enable a filter?

Comment: Just comment out or remove this line.

Comment: For this specific instance, I want to disable sending the standard WP password changed email while a function runs and then re-enable it.

Comment: put `remove_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );` at the end of the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you add functions to the same handle without specifying the priority, they are executed in the order of addition. Every time you try to send an email, all the hooked functions will be called in the order in which they were added.

To turn on email sending while a function runs, you can:

- remove `__return_false` from filter at the beginning of the function and add again at the end,
- add `__return_true` to filter (will be executed as second and override previous result) at the beginning of the function and remove it at the end.

Example:

```
function my_function() 
{
    add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_true' );
    //
    // sending an email about password change enabled
    //
    remove_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_true' );
}
```